# Glassfish There is a process already using the admin port 4848

Tags: linux, glassfish

```
asadmin start-domain domain1
```

But it shows this error.

```
 There is a process already using the admin port 4848 -- it probably is another instance of a GlassFish server.
```

I have searched and found that it could be the hostname or that the port is used by an other application or server and actually it is used by TCP.

I have no problem with the hostname so I've tried this solution by changing port.

```
  asadmin set server.http-service.http-listener.http-listener-1.port=10080
```

but it shows this error

```
remote failure: No configuration found for server.http-service.http-listener.http-listener-1
Command set failed.
```

I can't understand why.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: If you are pretty sure that no instance of Glassfish is running, check your hostname and ensure it resolves correctly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you are running glassifhs under linux

1 - Check if glassfish is already runnig.

```
ps -ef |grep java
```

kill any process java relative to glassfish

2 - Check if the port 4848 is in use

```
netstat -nao |grep 4848
```

3 - Change the default port

Edit the file {glassfish_home}/config/asadminenv.conf

```
AS_ADMIN_PORT=4848
```

Comment: I cant locate the file. This is what I find :
bex@bexlab:~/glassfish4/glassfish/config$ ls
`asenv.bat`  `asenv.conf`  `branding`  `client-jnlp-config.properties`  `glassfish.container`  `osgi.properties`

Comment: I encountered the same issue on CI server after upgrading to @actions/setup-java@v2, https://github.com/hantsy/jakartaee9-starter-boilerplate/runs/2293218091

Answer (score 7):

I hit the same error.

[This](https://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/when_there_is_a_process) was useful - i.e. check you can `ping $(hostname)`.  Looks like glassfish checks hostname against IP, possibly during bind process.

My issue was my hostname/ip address in `/etc/hosts` was not aligned correctly, meaning I could not `ping $(hostname)`.  Once aligned and pinged, glassfish started ok.

Comment: Just wanted to add on a Mac here I did not have a problem while trying to ping the hostname. However, it was necessary for me to add the hostname in the /etc/hosts file to resolve this issue.

Comment: And again for probably the 10th time I am here because I always forget about /etc/hosts

Comment: Hit the exact same issue myself. Having the host correctly defined solves the issue.

Answer (score 3):

I just kill all glassfish processes

```
 pkill -f glassfish
```

Answer (score 1):

I just hit this issue today. Be sure to delete the **$PATH/TO/domain1/config/pid** and **$PATH/TO/domain1/config/pid.prev** files as well, if the process isn't running but is being reported as still running.