# 4848 already in use when upgrading actions/setup-java to v2 in Github actions

Tags: github-actions, azul-zulu

The problem is similar to [Glassfish There is a process already using the admin port 4848](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44654024/glassfish-there-is-a-process-already-using-the-admin-port-4848), but my case is on Github actions.

I followed the [migrate guide](https://github.com/actions/setup-java/blob/main/docs/switching-to-v2.md), after upgrading to v2, all my workflow using Glassfish failed due to an error *4848 port is already in use*,

https://github.com/hantsy/jakartaee9-starter-boilerplate/blob/b3e51fcd857768c05e6104ea940f0ecd283c4698/.github/workflows/it-with-arq-glassfish-managed.yml#L22

But switch back to v1, works again.

https://github.com/hantsy/jakartaee9-starter-boilerplate/blob/master/.github/workflows/it-with-arq-glassfish-managed.yml#L22

Not sure why in @actions/setup-java@v2, port 4848 is used by some process.

**Update**: Return to v1, in the latest days occured the same problem.

I never encountered this issue before on Github actions. Now all workflow using Payara/Glassfish adapters failed.

- https://github.com/hantsy/jakartaee9-starter-boilerplate
- https://github.com/hantsy/jakartaee8-starter-boilerplate
- https://github.com/hantsy/cargotracker